# How to know if an image is already in a database?

Tags: java, android, sql, image-processing

I am writing a gallery image Android app but I do not know how to check if a new image already exists in my database. I am thinking somthing like that:

```
select * from images where id=md5(<new image>);
```

For every new image I get a md5 for this image. This md5 will be the primary key of the image in the database so later I can check if the image is in the database like you can see above.

Is this a good option? How can I know if an image is currently in the database? I think compare byte by byte images will be a heavy task, it is not?

Answer (score 0):

A checksum is divergent but not distinct, hence you should not use a primary key for it. Instead utilize it for a fail-fast approach:

```sql
create table images (
    id        integer  primary key,
    data      blob     ,
    checksum  raw(16)
);

select * from images where data = ? and id in (
  select id from images where checksum = ?
);
```

However, the probability of a checksum clash is fairly low, so doing the identity check on the data in `java` might perform even better than the nested statement.

To further increase performance (and dependent on the database) it might help to use an index on the `checksum`:

```sql
create index awesome_index_name on images(checksum);
```